# Session not closing after closed the pages?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, jmeter, load-testing

Am running web application just login and logout process,when i finished login process,within in a second clicked logout process,but in sql server activity monitor still showing previous session.
   Again refreshed same page same process repeated , its working perfectly . i was tested for 5 concurrent users same as session not closing .

checked web config , and other connectivity sources but didnt get solution for this , if anyone have experience share solution for this problem .

Answer (score 0):

store userid at the time of login in session. Remove the session in logout click

```
Session.Abandon();
```

and in the page load of master page check whether session is null or not

```
if(Session["uid"]=="")
  Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
```

Comment: Hi i was tried both but thats not working again getting same problem.i have checked several times same source,i have another doubt before logged out processes writing in log file all processes user done in one session , i think thats also problem ..for that commented particular code but its shows web config file error.